# Capturing the OnShutdown event in a .Net 6 Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, .net-6.0, application-shutdown

I have experience building Windows Services in .NET Framework 4.6 and Visual Studio 2017 – depending on the business logic complexity, they are really easy. I’m writing a new Window Service and, moving with the times, I’m writing it in .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022. I’m using the approved method in the Window Service template of inheriting from `BackgroundService`. My problem is that I can’t catch the OnShutdown event from the Service Controller when the server is shutting down or rebooting. The `BackgroundService` class includes `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`, but nothing for Shutdown.

Is there a way I can handle the server shutdown event using the `BackgroundService`?
This is very important to me as I need a way to shut down my service gracefully when the server reboots.

I found a way to ‘cheat’ – I created a Console app and installed `Core.System.ServiceProcess` from NuGet and then inherited from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase` instead in a class I created for the service. Then I could just override `OnStart`, `OnStop`, and `OnShutdown` as usual. However, I’d rather use the `BackgroundService` instead if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't `StopAsync` be invoked on the shutdown?

Comment: JIC - are you calling `UseWindowsService` on the builder?